# Unexpected behavior when assigning JSP getparameters to an array

Tags: java, jsp

Can someone please explain the following issue when I assign the results of request.getParameters to two different string array objects :

I assign the values of getParameterValues to two different string arrays
I then update the contents of one string array.
When I check the values of the other string array, they have also been changed.

```
// pseudo code below

// assign the values of getParameterValues to a string array
String[] obj1 = request.getParameterValues("some_parameters");

// assign the values of getParameterValues to another string array
String[] obj2 = request.getParameterValues("some_parameters");

// loop through the values of obj1 and update them
for(int i=0; i< obj1 .length; i++)
{
obj1[i] = obj1[i] + " UPDATED VALUE";
}


for(int i=0; i< obj2 .length; i++)
{
// output values in obj2 array 
// THESE HAVE BEEN UPDATED - WHY ?
}
```

Secondly, I run this code in the form of a JSP page running under Tomcat. We have two servers and this behavior was only exhibited one one of the Tomcat servers - i.e. on one Tomcat server, changing one string array did not affect the other. Is there a Tomcat setting which could explain this behavior ?

Many thanks in advance for your feedback !

Answer (score 0):

Because your container has chosen to always return the same array, instead of creating a new one, every time you get the parameter values of a given parameter. So `obj1 == obj2`.

I'm not sure why you're modifying the values of parameters, especially in a JSP, but if you want to avoid this problem, then create a copy of the array before modifying it:

```
String[] obj1 = (byte[]) request.getParameterValues("some_parameters").clone();
// or
String[] obj1 = request.getParameterValues("some_parameters");
obj1 = Arrays.copyOf(ob1, obj1.length)
```

Comment: would i be right in saying that request.getParameterValues is an object so : obj1 = objParameters; obj2 = objParameters; therefore obj1 == obj2 == objParameters ? is this because it's an array (object) of strings rather than a string - I don't get the same behavior when I work with a single string. Thanks!

Comment: Both String and arrays are objects. Strings are immutable, so there's no way for you to modify a String. Arrays are mutable.

Comment: Ahhh - that makes sense. Many thanks. Any idea why the behavior would be different on different servers ? This issue was only picked up when the code was migrated to another server.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe a different version, maybe you're not exactly using the same code?

Comment: thanks for taking the time to reply - much appreciated !